# What is Entity Framework's default Connection timeout for SQL Server?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

What is .NET entity framework default **Connection** timeout for SQL Server?

I am using mvc 4 and sql server 2014.

Anyone knows for sure?

**(This is not duplicate!
I asked about Connection time out, not about command timeout!!!)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the Documentation when using SQL.

Sql**Connetion**Timeout: The default is 15 seconds.

Sql**Command**Timeout: The default is 30 seconds.

[A good explanation about connection and command timeouts](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/docast/2018/10/11/connection-timeout-and-command-timeout-in-sql-server/)